# Access of an app denied because of not enabled/subscribed service

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I've a Azure Active Directory user from tenantB (directoryB) e.g. user@domainB.com

that tries to login to an app domainA.com on tenantA (directoryA).

I get the following error in redirect url:

> error_description=AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service (\"https://*.dps.mil/\") that your organization \"domainB.com\" has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.

And than I get redirected on login page.

I use https://login.microsoftonline.com/ login platform.

Comment: You need to register the application in tenant A as a mutile tenant application. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Sounds like there is a dependency on the app to an API that is not registered in the other tenant. Is that one of your APIs?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Did you find a solution?